# SharePoint Services 3.0 Language

Tags: wss-3.0, localization, language

First my apologies for a possibly old outdated question.

Working for a company that doesn't want to spring for the added costs of 2010 SharePoint services, but using SharePoint Services 3.0.

They have sites and work-spaces and all is fine. however, they want to expand it to sister companies, and change the language, based on the clients locale to different languages (i.e. Japanese, Chinese , German .... so on).

NOTE: This would be with existing English sites, that would just change the labels to the other language for display. Not just the install to create other sites in a different language from the home site. The site should be the same, just different displayed language based on client locale, or preferred language.

Is there a way to handle this within WSS 3.0, or do we need to go to 2010 to do it? Understanding that the content will NOT translate, just looking for the headers, labels and so fourth, should just be resource files installed and a locale check....